# 3d array allocation by void function

Tags: c, multiple-indirection

I obtain a Segmentation Fault when i=0 and j=2;
But I don't know why !

Could you help me ?

That's my function :

```
void allocationdynamiquetableautroisdimdentier(int**** Matrice,int nbniveau, int nbligne, int nbcolonne)
{
int i,j;
    *Matrice=(int***) malloc (sizeof(int**)*nbniveau);
    for (i=0; i<nbniveau; i++)
    {
        (*(Matrice))[i]=(int**) malloc (sizeof(int*)*nbligne);  // allocation dynamique de la matrice Matrice
        for (j=0; j<nbligne; i++)
        {
            ((*(Matrice))[i])[j]=(int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*nbcolonne);
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: A triple pointer, really???? oh god why?

Comment: @TonyTheLion read again. There are 4 asterisks.

Comment: There are certainly more efficient ways to implement this, and there are way too many unnecessary parentheses but I can't see why it would fault unless malloc is returning NULL.

Comment: It might be more reasonable to allocate a flat array and have helper functions for translating between (i,j,k) to a flat index, and back.

Comment: How could j ever equal 2, if you never increment j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        for (j=0; j<nbligne; i++)
```

should be

```
        for (j=0; j<nbligne; j++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `i++` in *both* loop statements!